# User Disablement notification not working in WSO2 5.9 Idenitity Server with PostgreSQL

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

When I am trying to get the user disablement notification in wso2 5.9 identity server with DB as postgreSQL, we are getting below error:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-05-13 13:30:00,742] [] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.account.suspension.notification.task.AccountValidatorThread}
- Unable to disable user accounts org.wso2.carbon.identity.base.IdentityException: Error occurred while retrieving users for account disable
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.base.IdentityException.error(IdentityException.java:60)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.account.suspension.notification.task.AccountValidatorThread.lockAccounts(AccountValidatorThread.java:205)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.account.suspension.notification.task.AccountValidatorThread.handleTask(AccountValidatorThread.java:158)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.account.suspension.notification.task.AccountValidatorThread.run(AccountValidatorThread.java:76)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.identity.account.suspension.notification.task.exception.AccountSuspensionNotificationException: ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = character varying   Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.   Position: 240
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.account.suspension.notification.task.jdbc.JDBCNotificationReceiversRetrieval.getNotificationReceivers(JDBCNotificationReceiversRetrieval.java:132)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.account.suspension.notification.task.NotificationReceiversRetrievalManager.getReceivers(NotificationReceiversRetrievalManager.java:65)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.account.suspension.notification.task.AccountValidatorThread.lockAccounts(AccountValidatorThread.java:201)
        ... 9 more 
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = character varying   Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.   Position: 240
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2505)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2241)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:310)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:447)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:368)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:158)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:108)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor37.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy54.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.account.suspension.notification.task.jdbc.JDBCNotificationReceiversRetrieval.getNotificationReceivers(JDBCNotificationReceiversRetrieval.java:95)
        ... 11 more
```

Comment: Could you please mention the PostgreSQL version that you are using?

Comment: I am using version PostgreSQL 10.12